# Disable console warning IE developer tool

Tags: internet-explorer, ie-developer-tools

Is it possible to disable all console messages in IE developer tool by default and only enable errors.
Every time I try to debug I need to to disable all logs from filters and then enable only errors.

Is there any registry entry that we can set and which disables all console logs and enable only error logs?

Comment: Why do you need to "need to disable all logs from filters"?

Comment: You might consider fixing the warnings so you don't get so many that you need to turn them off.